What drink riding law applies to electrically assisted pedal cycles?
TL/DR: Is the DUI law for the base class of E-bikes the same as for motor vehicles, or the same as for pedal cycles?
Long question:
Bicycles with electric motors have various categories.  The lowest is electrically assisted pedal cycles, which have these restrictions:

Electric assistance can only be provided to a maximum of 25kph (15.5mph).
The motor used must be of no more than 250 Watts (maximum continuous rated power).
The e-bike’s pedals must be in motion for motor assistance to be provided.

My understanding was that these are much the same as unpowered bicycles, with the only difference being a minimum age limit of 14.  It is worth noting that unlike other classes they can be ridden in bike lanes  However the above linked page says:

speed limits apply to e-bikes, as do offences relating to failing to stop at the scene of an accident (‘hit-and-run’), and offences relating to mobile phone use while ‘driving’, drink/drug ‘driving’. E-cycle riders can also be convicted of offences for ‘careless’ and dangerous’ driving, along with their ‘causing death by…’ and ‘causing serious injury by…’ variants.

My understanding is that drink driving/riding is governed by the Road Traffic Act 1988 with section 4-5 covering cars:

4 Driving, or being in charge, when under influence of drink or drugs.
(1) A person who, when driving or attempting to drive a [F1mechanically propelled vehicle] on a road or other public place, is unfit to drive through drink or drugs is guilty of an offence.
5 Driving or being in charge of a motor vehicle with alcohol concentration above prescribed limit.
(1) If a person—
drives or attempts to drive a motor vehicle on a road or other public place, or
after consuming so much alcohol that the proportion of it in his breath, blood or urine exceeds the prescribed limit he is guilty of an offence.

and section 30 covering bikes:

30 Cycling when under influence of drink or drugs.
(1) A person who, when riding a cycle on a road or other public place, is unfit to ride through drink or drugs (that is to say, is under the influence of drink or a drug to such an extent as to be incapable of having proper control of the cycle) is guilty of an offence.

It is worth noting that on the same page, titled "Cycling offences and cycle racing" is section 32:

32 Electrically assisted pedal cycles.
(1) An electrically assisted pedal cycle of a class specified in regulations made for the purposes of section 189 of this Act and section 140 of the M1Road Traffic Regulation Act 1984 shall not be driven on a road by a person under the age of fourteen.

My reading of this is that electrically assisted pedal cycles are covered by the alcohol regulations in section 30 as are unpowered cycles.  This does not have a specified  prescribed limit.  Is this reading correct?

It looks like e-bikes are governed by the motor vehicle regulations, except where specified otherwise, like section 32, rather than bicycle regulations.

The question title isn't clear. Is it why don't e-bike riders have a mandatory alcohol limit as do other self-propelled vehicles? Perhaps because it is not self-propelled: the motor will only assist if the rider is pedalling.

@WeatherVane I think such a why question would be off topic.  The question is if the rules in section 4-5 or section 30 apply to electrically assisted pedal cycles.

The question is still unclear. Is it is the DUI law for the base class of E-bikes the same as for motor vehicles, or the same as for pedal cycles? There's too much fluff in the question.

@WeatherVane I like your elegant summary, I have added it as a TL/DR.  It seems having the reason for my confusion and the relevant law in the question makes sense.

There are two key terms in law:

mechanically propelled vehicle (MPV) - e.g. one which has some kind of motor. a normal bicycle is NOT an MPV, but if it has a motor, then it is. this is a 'common language definition', not a definition set out in legislation
motor vehicle (MV) is a MPV intended or adapted for use on the roads

Under RTA s 189 1(c) a 'legal' EAPC (one with motor-assist speed limit & wattage limit) is not a  MV. This does not however mean it's not a MPV.
Then, looking at the sections of the RTA:

dangerous/careless/inconsiderate driving applies to MPVs
death while uninsured/unlicensed/disqualified applies to MVs
driving while under the influence applies to MPVs
driving/being in charge with BAC or drug over specified limit applies to MVs
riding a cycle while under the influence applies to cycles
speed limits apply to MVs
failing to stop applies to MPVs.
mobile phone offences apply to MVs

So the linked page is substantially wrong:

it's lawful to use a mobile phone while riding an ebike, because an ebike is not a motor vehicle but an MPV, unless this constitutes careless driving or careless cycling.
speed limits do not apply, as not a MV
however causing death etc. by careless e-bike riding is a serious offence (death by careless or inconsiderate driving - 5 years in prison), whereas causing death by a non e-bike is not at all a serious offence, as it can only be charged under 'careless cycling' (a very minor offence) or 'furious driving' under OAPA - it's very difficult to impose harsh sentences on cyclists driving normal bicycles
drunken e-bike riding is covered under RTA s4(1) which carries a 6 month sentence.
this is less serious then MVs: the test here is "if his ability to drive properly is for the time being impaired."
however, it is more serious than for a non-MPV cycle: "under the influence of drink or a drug to such an extent as to be incapable of having proper control of the cycle", which only carries a sentence of a level 3 fine (£1000)
the rules for MVs are much stricter - it's an offence not to give an alcohol sample, and the offence of having BAC over the limit is strict - it's not necessary to be objectively drunk, and the sentence is up to 51 weeks
an e-scooter in a trial rental scheme is a MV (since in general a MPV is an MV unless excluded), and therefore you can be compelled to give a breath sample.


Bicycles are vehicles
australia
Australia’s road rules are universal (mostly) but implemented by legislation in each state and territory, so I’ll quote from new-south-wales.
s11 of the Road Rules 2014 state that they apply to
“vehicles and road users on roads and road related areas.” s17 defines a rider as a person riding a bicycle (among other things). s19 states that a reference to a driver includes a rider (ono). s110 says drivers must not be drunk.
So, by that long series of connections, a bicycle rider must not be over the limit.

See? The question remains unclear. A motorbike rider will tested for a specific alcohol limit as proscribed by the law. A bike rider will not, but still must not be DUI. What happens to the base class of E-bike riders? The question seems to be "what does over the limit mean for those E-bikers?"

@WeatherVane what’s unclear? They have the same limit as any other driver. 0.05 normally or 0.02 if they are a professional rider (e.g. deliver driver)

Please read the very unclear question again, which tries to point out that there are specific differences in the legislation.

@WeatherVane not in Australia

Oh, ok, it's not unclear in NSW.
